# How to solve a specific situation in Perforce involving changes which I do not want to be propagated to other branches?

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream

So, here's the situation. I have 2 streams, "Development.Main" and "Development.A" (child of Development.Main). I will focus only on the "path" that one file took through my "versioning" steps that I executed.

1. The file starts out in Main.
2. I merge it down to A with no changes.
3. I delete it in Main.
4. When I go to merge the changes in Main down to A, I choose to "Keep Target", so that the file remains undeleted in A, because **I want the file deleted in Main, but not in A**.
5. But then the Perforce stream diagram tells me that I have files to copy from A to Main (see the green arrow). And when I go to do the Copy operation (from A to Main) it wants to copy the file back into Main, thereby regenerating it. But I want it to stay deleted. *Note that, when I try to force a merge (instead of a copy) from A to Main, Perforce thinks that there is nothing to merge and it decides to respond with an error. See image #3 below*

## 1 - Stream Diagram

[image: Stream Diagram]

## 2 - Revision Graph

[image: Revision Graph]

## 3 - Trying to force the merge from A to Main

[image: Error when trying to force merge]

How do I solve this situation, so that I can delete the file in Main but not in A?

Conditions for the solution:

1. I want all green arrows to go away on the stream diagram.
2. From now on, I don't want this file to show up in the Copy (from A to Main) operation. (Because I don't want this file to show up in Main again. It's supposed to be deleted there.)
3. I don't want to change anything about the stream spec or workspace spec just for this specific file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**Option one (general solution):**

Don't ever do the `copy` operation between these two streams.  The **merge**/**copy** workflow is not compatible with the idea of "ignoring" changes, because as soon as you `copy` you force the two streams to be identical regardless of what has previously been ignored.

Fortunately, streams have a `mergeany` option that allows you to opt out of the **merge**/**copy** workflow, so you can instead **merge**/**merge** without having to use the `-F` (force) flag each time -- this was the standard Perforce workflow before streams existed.  When you `merge`, previously "ignored" revisions will not be merged, nor will revisions that were themselves the product of an "ignore" in the reverse direction (i.e. your ignored delete will not re-propagate as an add if you're doing a merge).

The ability to "ignore" branch/delete operations in this way is described in more detail here (again, note that this only works with `merge`/`integrate`, not `copy`): https://web.archive.org/web/20141020052100/http://www.perforce.com:80/blog/110620/ignoring-branches-deletes

**Option two (for entire files only):**

Since this is an entire file that you don't want to propagate, rather than a specific revision, you can `isolate` it in `Development.A`'s `Paths`.  This will remove it from the integration view so that no changes made to that file will propagate (in either direction, regardless of whether you're merging or copying).  From the point of view of the `copy`, this file is simply no longer part of your stream.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but... 1. When I try to force a merge (instead of a copy) from A to Main, no files show up in the changelist (Perforce thinks there is nothing to merge). 2. I don't want to change the stream spec or workspace spec just for this 1 file. (There are actually a lot of other files that are in the same boat.) I edited my question to include this info.

Comment: Why is (1) a problem?  You don't want to merge this file (that would cause it to be re-added to main), so the fact that nothing is opened when you go to merge means that it's working exactly correctly.

Comment: I made a mistake. I know I tried the forced merge in the past and it didn't work - but I didn't correctly remember what went wrong. What happens when I try that, is that I actually don't even get a changelist. Perforce doesn't let me get that far. I get the error message above (which I just added to my question).

Comment: Again, that seems like the correct behavior.  What did you expect to have happen, given that *the file has already been integrated and you don't want to integrate it again*?  (Are there **other**, unintegrated, files that are erroneously being skipped, or is this one file that you don't want to integrate the only file that is not being integrated, which is exactly what you want?  I'm honestly confused what the problem is here.)

Comment: I want the green Copy arrow to go away. I mean, in the future, I will have real stuff to copy from A to Main, and I don't want these "deleted" files to pop up in that Copy changelist.

Comment: In that case you want option (2).  There is no solution that will satisfy both of your constraints, because the concept of "I want you to make this thing an exact copy of this other thing" is not compatible with the concept of "I want these two things to be different".  :)  The only way to have  "copy" give you different sets of files is if some of those files are completely excluded from the operation, and that will require explicitly excluding them in the stream definition.

Comment: In other words, from now on, when I do a Copy from A to Main, I do not want these files to show up in the Changelist.

Comment: Updated my (1) to clarify that it means you **never** copy between these streams from now on (that's why the `mergeany` option exists, to let you `merge`/`merge` without having to "force" it).  We're at the comment thread limit so if you have more questions I encourage you to post on the Perforce forums.  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204076/discussion-between-n73k-and-sam-stafford).